# Fetch privacy list of user using Facebook App

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Can anyone suggest me how to fetch privacy list of a user through facebook-graph-api or FQL? I need to poll questions on user's facebook-wall using my app giving him option to limit visibility of the questions on UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest me how to fetch privacy list of a user through facebook-graph-api or FQL?

You mean their default privacy settings they have in place for their wall posts etc.?

Can’t be done.

> I need to poll questions on user's facebook-wall using my app giving him option to limit visibility of the questions on UI.

The user themselves can limit the visibility of anything your app will post on their behalf, in the Auth dialog when first connecting to your app, and then afterwards in their account settings.

There is no parameter an app could use to set privacy options on-the-fly while posting a new question.

You could set the *Default Activity Privacy* in your app’s settings to *only me* – but, as said, the user can overwrite this any time they like.

Comment: Thanks for replying CBroe. I know that user can overwrite it anytime. But what I basically want is to show the list which comes to UI(next to POST button) when user manually asks question on his wall. Can you help me in it? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Again, there __is no way__ of doing that with an app via the API. Only the dialogs that Facebook provides to be called by an app do partially have that feature – but there is no dialog for posting questions yet.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. I will let you know if I will find something remarkable in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a user's default visibility setting for posts made from your app using the following FQL query [[1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting)]:

```
SELECT name, value, description, allow, deny, networks, friends FROM privacy_setting WHERE name = "default_stream_privacy"
```

Some objects (Albums for sure, possibly timeline posts? [undocumented]...) allow you to specify visibility settings at the time of creation PROVIDED THAT the visibility settings do not exceed the scope of the default visibility setting.

The privacy settings for a specific object (once created) can be retrieved using the FQL query [[2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy)]:

```
SELECT value, description FROM privacy WHERE id = 10151177771869615
```